# Python-add a list to end of a file

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to create function that would take a file variable and a customer record (as a list) as parameters and adds that customer information to the end of the file. Example:

```
> f = open( "customers.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8" )
> data = ['2134', 'Lee', 'Stan', 287.56, '2008-10-10']
> append_customer( f, data )
```

Right now Here is the code I have currently:

```
add_record=input("Enter the record you want to enter: ")


l = open(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\Eclipse\customers.txt','a', encoding="utf-8")

contents= l.readlines()

def get_new_customer(contents, add_record):
    new_record=[]
    for new_record in add_record:
        new_record+= add_record
        contents.write(new_record)

l.close()

get_new_customer(contents,add_record)
```

However, I get an error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\Eclipseee\\customers.txt'
```

Due to this error I'm not even sure if my code would even work regardless of the ERRNO 13 permission error.

If anyone has any suggestions/comments, please advise!
~GIO~

Comment: `add_record` is a string, not a list of strings like in your `data` example. Why you have no access to your file, dont know. Maybe its already opened?

Comment: @Marcin, nope its not open

Comment: I think "permission denied" is the least of the problems with your code. For example, in addition to my first comment, `contents.write(new_record)` will not work. `contents` is a list, not a file object.

Comment: You're opening the file in append mode (`'a'`), but then you call `readlines()` on it. To read from it, you'll need to open it in read mode (`'r'`). You could also try commenting out the `contents = l.readlines()` to see if that changes things.

Comment: @Shaun, tried that but to no avail my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can be simplified:

```
def get_new_customer(fh, add_record):  
    # join record data into a string  
    new_line = ",".join(add_record)
    # write it to the last line of the file
    fh.write(new_line + "\n")


# Customer data separted by comma
add_record=input("Enter the record you want to enter: ")

# get costumer data as list by spliting on coma
data = add_record.split(',')

# open the file and add the customer data to it.
with open(r'/tmp/customers.txt','a+', encoding="utf-8") as l:
    get_new_customer(l, data)
```

Comment: hey man, awesome work, I like how you broke it down to make it much more simplified. I tried it on my editor(ECLIPSE), and still end up with the permission denied "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\John,etc".. I did change up the 2nd last line of your respective code to my txt files location but to no avail

Comment: @Giovanni Thx. I dont know why you have permission error. Maybe try making new file in different folder, to see if it happens again.

Comment: ah nevermind, figured it out, basically my txt file when I right clicked it was set as "read-only" so I unchecked it and vola !